# How to do conditional right join in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have two tables like this

[image]

Now I want to do right join `Menu_Table` with `Menu_access_Table`.

I want to get all rows from `Menu_Table`.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    Menu_Table
RIGHT JOIN 
    Menu_Access_Table ON Menu_Table.menu_id = Menu_Access_Table.menu_id
WHERE
    Menu_Access_Table.user_id=11
```

If there is no entry under `user_id=11` I still want to get all rows from `Menu_Table`! Is it possible? I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get all rows from `Menu_Table`, you want to do a `LEFT JOIN`, not a `RIGHT JOIN`.

You can just put the additional condition in the `ON`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Menu_Table
LEFT JOIN Menu_Access_Table ON Menu_Table.menu_id = Menu_Access_Table.menu_id
    AND Menu_Access_Table.user_id = 11
```